# UIScrollView renders different when switching back and forth using UITabBar

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of days now and I can't seem to find any concrete solution online, so here it goes...

**The scenario is simple:** I want the table view to be expanded (i.e. not scrollable) in a scroll view, and therefore I need to resize and move the view(s) within the scroll view. This I have achieved quite easy by sub classing the UIScrollView and re-implemented the layoutSubviews method (see below).

**Implementation of the layoutSubViews:**

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
 [super layoutSubviews];
  //Resize the UITableView containing all the rows (i.e. it should not scroll within the tableview)
  UITableView *bt = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
  //1 - Set the height of the table cells

  //2 - Calculate the total height for the tableview (i.e.: numberOfRows*rowHeight)
  bt.frame = CGRectMake(bt.frame.origin.x, bt.frame.origin.y, bt.frame.size.width, ([bt numberOfRowsInSection:0]*bt.rowHeight));

  //Move down the note text view, so that it don't overlaps the table.
  UITextView *note = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
  note.frame = CGRectMake(note.frame.origin.x, (bt.frame.origin.y + bt.frame.size.height)+15, note.frame.size.width, note.frame.size.height);

  //Set the content size to the scroll view.
  //Note: If the note is hidden, then we should not include it (the same goes for the padding between note and table)
  [self setContentSize: CGSizeMake(self.contentSize.width, bt.frame.size.height + note.frame.size.height)];

  UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, /*padding@bottom*/50.0f, 0.0f);
  [self setContentInset:insets];
  [self setScrollIndicatorInsets:insets];
}
```

The implementation above solves my problems and renders perfectly. Try to think of it as rendering an recipe where each row in the table view is an ingredient - that is what I'm aiming for.

My app is utilizing the UITabBar and everything renders and behave fine except for the case when I scroll down a bit in the scroll view and then switch to another tab and back. The scroll view is then somehow altered and it is no longer possible to scroll to the top (depending on how much you've scrolled down before switching tab) and is also rendered somewhat strange.

**Step 1:** Step1.png (see URL below)

Scrolled down to be able to see the textview below expanded tableview

**Step 2:** step2-switched-back.png (See URL below)

Switching to Second tab and back to First, causing odd rendering behavior and scrolling behavior where it is no longer possible to reach the first row in tableview by scrolling the scroll view.

I've created an example project since I believe the code talks for itself, and I hope someone out there can see through this and point out if I've done something wrong or if there are any way to get round this.
**Project & screenshots available at:** http://eddiex.se/tmp/demo/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now come up with an alternative solution that will give me the same rendering as I was aiming for with having a UITableView expanded inside a UIScrollView.

**Solution**

I removed the UIScrollView (Editor->Unembed) and set the size of the UITableView to cover whole screen (in UI editor) and I, visually in UI editor, moved the UITextFieldView in to the UITableView (as footer view).

The tiny shadow (gradient view) below the last row in the expanded table was also easy to implement within this solution since no change was needed; UITableView's delegate implemented viewForFooterInSection method, which returned a simple gradient view.